# How do I start a different method over after another Method has finished in java?

Tags: java, loops, methods

I'm making a gambling game. The player enters a bet amount. After that a die is rolled three times, then based on the value of the die rolls, 1 of 4 things happen. Then you get to start again with the new Pot amount. I cant figure out how to start it again. I tried putting the method name i want to start at the end of the last method in the sequence and it kinda of works. It starts but when i put in a bet amount it doesnt do anything.

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    private double Bet;
    private double Pot = 50;
    // private double TotalPot;
    private int[] die = new int[3];

    public Game() {
        Pot = 50;
        Bet = 0;
    }

    public void introText() {
        System.out.println(
                "Welcome to game Bet an amount.\nIf all of the three die together is greater than 12, \nyou get to keep your bet, if you roll doubles you win \ndouble your bet, if you roll triples you win triple \nyour bet. If your roll meets non of this criteria you lose your bet.A bet of 0 \nends the game.");
    }

    public void inputBet() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your bet: ");
        Bet = keyboard.nextDouble();
        if (Bet > Pot) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Error, Bet out of range. Please enter a bet amount that is lower or the same as the current Pot. ");

            inputBet();
        } else if (Bet == 0) {
            System.out.println("Thank you for playing. You end the game with a pot of " + Pot);
            System.exit(1);
        } else if (Bet < 0) {
            System.out.println("Error,");

            inputBet();
        }
    }

    public void removeBet() {
        Pot = Pot - Bet;
    }

    public void rollDie() {
        Die bob = new Die();
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            die[i] = bob.rollDie();
            System.out.println("Your die number is listed below");
            bob.displayDie(die[i]);
            total = total + die[i];
        }
        bob.displayDie(total);
    }

    public void displayingDie() {
        System.out.println("Pot amount before dice rolls $" + Pot);
    }

    public void dieComparison1() {
        if ((die[1] == die[2]) && (die[0] == die[2])) {
            Pot = (Bet * 3) + Pot;
            System.out.println(+Pot + "if theyre all equal");
        } else if ((die[0] == die[1]) || (die[0] == die[2]) || (die[1] == die[2])) {
            Pot = (Bet * 2) + Pot;
            System.out.println(" Congradulations! You win double your bet.");
        } else if (die[0] + die[1] + die[2] > 12) {
            Pot = Pot + Bet;
            System.out.println("You win. But only your bet amount back");
        } else if (die[0] + die[1] + die[2] < 12) {
            // Pot = Pot - Bet;
            System.out.println("Sorry You lose you bet amount");
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("The current Pot amount is: " + Pot);
        inputBet();
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are doing is actually called recursion.  There are many reasons to use recursion, but, not in your case.

Comment: for example look at this [link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/java-recursion-example/), in your problem you can set `bet` and `pot` as  `inputBet` method argument like `public void inputBet(double bet,double pot)`, so you can change`Bet` and `Pot` as per your requirement

Comment: @Michael Quatrani so how do I get to program to start over but keep the same pot amount

Comment: @PatrickDempsey working on it give me a couple min pls :)

Comment: you can use a `while(true)` loop in your main method ,which keep running  your program forever !

Comment: is the Player in Player.inputBet();  supposed to be my main name? I tried that and it said that the method inputBet located in the class i posted needed to be static. so changed it to static (by the way i forget what static means) and then my if statements had a bunch of error messages @Michael Quatrani

Comment: @PatrickDempsey not sure what you mean, main name.  it's supposed to be an object.

Comment: @ Patrick Dempsey can you include your execution flow or main method code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have a conception problem. You should not control your execution flow nor do io actions from your Game class. This is mainly a problem of separation of concerns. Each method of this class should only do actions relative to gambling. For exemple inputBet must only change bet and do controls, in fact it must only be a setter and be renamed setBet and throws IllegalArgumentException for exemple.

You can then do something like this in your main :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Game game = new Game();

    while(true){
        Double bet = keyboard.nextDouble();
        if(bet == 0){
           //main loop break case
           break;
        }
        try{
            game.setBet(bet);
        }catch(IllegalArguementException excpt){
            system.out.println("error " + excpt.getMessage());
            // skip next steps and do new loop iteration
            continue;
        }
        // rest of execution flow
        game.rollDice();
        game.displayDice();
        game.compareDice();
        game.print();
    }

    System.exit(0);
}
```

and the setBet method could be :

```
public void setBet(Double bet){
     // Range controls
     if (bet > Pot || bet < 0) {
           Throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bet out of range. Please enter a bet amount that is lower or the same as the current Pot. ");
     }
     this.bet = bet;   
}
```